# How to clip an SVG within an SVG?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to add an SVG to an SVG and clip it. In this example the external SVG is named `box.svg` and is embedded using an `image` tag.

When the `clip-path` attribute is present, the box disappears. When removed, the box shows up. After toying with `viewBox` and `clipPathUnits` and even `xmlns` I still can't find a solution.

`box.svg`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="32" height="32">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"></rect>                       
</svg>
```

`test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                        
<html>                                                                                                 
<head>                                                                                                 
  <title></title>                                                                                      
</head>                                                                                                
<body>                                                                                                 
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewbox="0 0 200 200">                                                 
  <defs>                                                                                               
    <clip-path id="cliparea">                                                                          
            <polygon points="95 43 104 43 151 123 146 132 53 132 48 123"></polygon>                    
    </clip-path>                                                                                       
  </defs>                                                                                              
  <polygon stroke="#0F0" points="95 43 104 43 151 123 146 132 53 132 48 123" id="poly-gitea"></polygon>
  <image x="60" y="60" width="80" height="80" clip-path="url(#cliparea)" href="/box.svg">              
  </image></svg>                                                                                       
</body>                                                                                                
</html>
```

Comment: The element is clipPath not clip-path. Using clip-path for the attribute name is correct though.

Comment: Ugh. So simple! Thanks for pointing out my mistake.